# inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: invalid address

Tags: javascript, transactions, ethereum, web3js

This is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract test{
mapping(string => address payable) pizzaPlace;
address contractOwner;
address payable userWallet;
constructor() public{
    contractOwner=msg.sender;
    pizzaPlace["piaazOne"]=0xd806F6b4888ff997dB4A073fD9EdD40ab92BCbD4;
}
function paymentHandlerer() public payable returns(bool){
        userWallet = pizzaPlace["pizzaOne"];
        userWallet.transfer(msg.value);
        return true;
}
function showMessage() public view returns(string memory){
    return "Hello Solidity";
}
```

I have been learning solidity for a while but this is something I seem not to tackle.
The above contract was written in remix and I am using Ganache on my local machine to deploy contracts.

Following is my code for function call:

```
const contractAddress = '0xEe1C4287b37de1ADFE2aD78C7B7c96D7694093cb';
const contractAbi=[...];
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
contract.showMessage(function (error, message) {
    $("#targetText").html(message);
});
const btn = document.querySelector("#sendEtherBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
contract.paymentHandlerer(
{"to":contractAddress,
 "from":web3.eth.accounts[0],
 "value":web3.toWei("10.0","ether")
});
});
```

When I run this code. The function showMessage() does get called as I see the message "Hello Solidity" on my browser screen. This proves that the contract is running fine. In the second function, I want to transfer some ether from msg.sender to the receiver but the function runs into an error all the time.

The error goes like this:

```
Uncaught Error: invalid address
at c (inpage.js:1)
at inputTransactionFormatter (inpage.js:1)
at inpage.js:1
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at o.formatInput (inpage.js:1)
at o.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
at w.e [as sendTransaction] (inpage.js:1)
at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:1)
at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.html:101)
```

Can anyone please help me solve it.
Also, I am not using node js or anything just plain Js and JQuery

Answer (score 0):

In `Web3.js` v1.0, `web3.eth.accounts` is not populated by default.

Instead, you need to get accounts using something like:

```js
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
> ["0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe", "0xDCc6960376d6C6dEa93647383FfB245CfCed97Cf"]
```

Comment: so what should I use to trigger the function call without any errors

Comment: @SurajShrestha Get addresses by calling `web3.eth.getAccounts()` instead of using `web3.eth.accounts[0]` to set the `from` field